# Find the lenght of the segment that links a point to the vertical diameter

Tags: geometry, circles, polar-coordinates

Given a circumference and a point on that, how can I compute the length of the line that links the point to the vertical diameter?

What I know is: the coordinates of the center (`cx` and `cy)`, the angle `theta1`, the radius and the coordinates of the point.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bm5r.jpg)

This is what I tried:

```
theta1 = degToRad(225°)
p1x = r * cos(theta1)
p1y = r * sin(theta1)
theta2 = 2 * PI - abs(PI - theta1)
p2x = r * cos(theta2)
p2y = r * sin(theta2)
dist = distance(p1, p2)
```

The idea is find the point `p2` which is the point mirrored with respect to the diameter and then compute the distance between two points.
It doesn't work, I think the problem is the computation of `theta2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overcomplicating things. This is a right triangle:

[image]

So basic trigonometry says
$$
? = r\sin\left(\theta - \frac{\pi}{2}\right).
$$